# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - while using UMAP

Tags: python, data-science, runumap

```
import umap as UMAP

import umap


retarget = {df_train['target'].value_counts().reset_index()['index'][i]: i for i in range(len(df_train['target'].value_counts()))}
retarget2 = {i: k for k, i in retarget.items()}
df_train['target'] = df_train['target'].map(retarget)

umap = umap(n_components = 2, n_neighbors = 10, min_dist = 0.99).fit_transform(df_train.drop('target', axis = 1).sample(15000, random_state = 228), df_train['target'].sample(15000, random_state = 228))
```

I am trying to use UMAP for visualization but it is keep on giving me error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bb51a04f463b> in <module>
      8 df_train['target'] = df_train['target'].map(retarget)
      9 
---> 10 umap = umap(n_components = 2, n_neighbors = 10, min_dist = 0.99).fit_transform(df_train.drop('target', axis = 1).sample(15000, random_state = 228), df_train['target'].sample(15000, random_state = 228))
     11 
     12 plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have umap installed in my system:

```
(base) C:\Users\bakumari\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>pip install umap
Collecting umap
  Using cached umap-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: umap
Successfully installed umap-0.1.1
```

I am trying to use umap for visualization purpose.

Comment: I have never used this module before, but the issue in your code is that `umap` is a module. You are directly using that module as a function, and that obviously will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `umap-learn`

```
pip uninstall umap
pip install umap-learn
```

and then

```
import umap
umap = umap.UMAP(n_components = 2, n_neighbors = 10, min_dist = 0.99).fit_transform(df_train.drop('target', axis = 1).sample(15000, random_state = 228), df_train['target'].sample(15000, random_state = 228))
```

Comment: I did follow the steps but now I am getting a new error:

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f743d4f1c330> in <module>
      6 df_train['target'] = df_train['target'].map(retarget)
      7 
----> 8 umap = umap(n_components = 2, n_neighbors = 10, min_dist = 0.99).fit_transform(df_train.drop('target', axis = 1).sample(15000, random_state = 228), df_train['target'].sample(15000, random_state = 228))
      9 
     10 plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I have edited it, check now

Comment: pip uninstall umap
pip install umap-learn
These 2 commands completed successfully

Comment: Change your last line and remove the first line